# Assigning alias to object passed as parameter to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, ecmascript-6

In this function I have this object `{ email, password }` passed to it

```
static login = ({ email, password }) => {
        const body = { email, password };
        callApi(body);
}
```

So to access the whole object I need to re-assign the values to the object 'body' in my case. Can't I access the whole object some other way something like this

```
static login = (body : { email, password }) => {
        callApi(body);
}
```

so I don't have to re-assign it.